# Denote the elimination of the row and the column corresponding a matrix element?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given a matrix A, e.g.
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11}&  a_{12} & a_{13} \\
a_{21}&  a_{22} & a_{23} \\
a_{31}&  a_{32} & a_{33} \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
eliminating the row and the column corresponding $a_{21}$ results in a smaller matrix
$$
B=\begin{bmatrix}
a_{12} & a_{13} \\
  a_{32} & a_{33} \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Is there a denotation for such resultant matrix B? Matrix cofactor involves similar operation but it does not gives a matrix.

Comment: Your last sentence does not make clear whether you are interested to the denotation of submatrices or rather to that of cofactors (or minors).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only place I remember seeing special notation is in Steven Roman's "Advanced Linear Algebra".

> Let $A \in \mathcal{M}_{n \times m}(\mathbb{F}),\, A=[a_{ij}].$ If $B \subseteq\{1,\ldots,n\}$ and $C\subseteq\{1,\ldots,m\},$ then 
>   $\,A[B,C]\,$ denotes the submatrix of $A$ that results in removing all rows that are not in $B$ and all columns that are not in $C.$

I don't know if this notation is widely used, but I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

This is a type of submatrix that one obtains by removing a select number of rows and columns. In your case, you eliminated the second row and first column, so a common notation is that this is a $(2,1)$-submatrix of $A$. Minors and cofactors are obtained through determinants of certain submatrices. Check out this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_(mathematics)#Submatrix) for more information.

Another common notation is found [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Submatrix). In your example, as the second row and first column are removed, the resulting matrix $B$ would be denoted $A(2;1)$ in this notation.