# What is the proper set notation for describing base-2 numbers within a certain range?

Tags: notation

I want to describe a range of base-2 values, e.g. $[8, 16, 32, 64]$, ascribed to a particular variable $k$ in set notation or some other form of concise (but easily understood) mathematical description, what would be an appropriate and concise way of describing this range?

I was thinking, for instance, something along the lines of: $\{k = 2^{n}\ , n \in \mathbb{Z} : 1 \le n \le 5\}$ but I have a feeling it is not mathematically correct or far too verbose for what I'm trying to describe.

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2424974). Also, I'd drop the $k=$. Finally, $\{2^n|n\in S\}$ could be denoted $2^S$, [but that could confuse people](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notation for the set is $\{2^n:n\in \Bbb Z, 1\le n\le 5\}$ or $\{2^n\mid n\in \Bbb Z, 1\le n \le 5\}$. Notice that $n\in \Bbb Z$ goes **after** the $:$ or $\mid$.

If you want to say a variable $k$ is taking those values you can write $k\in \{2^n\mid n\in \Bbb Z, 1\le n \le 5\}$.

However, in practice, in most mathematical writings you'll find something like

"We take $k = 2^n$ with $n = 1, 2, \ldots, 5$"